# Want to hide Navbar on Login Page of React application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React-Router and below from my App.js
I am able to hide Navbar with conditional statement but post successful login, when I redirect to Dashboard component , Navbar doesn't appear there.
But When I do browser refresh, I could see navBar on Dashboard page.
I believe because browser refresh start rendering App, if not it just renders next components.

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
    {window.location.pathname==="/login" ? null : <Navbar /> } 
    <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
    <section className="container">
      <Alert />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/create-profile' component={CreateProfile} />
    </Switch>
    </section>
    </Fragment>

    </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: When asking question, enclose any code within the code sample. This will improve the questions clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route file like this

```
    function App() {

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
                    ... // your code
                </Fragment>

            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
   }
```

NavComponent like this

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
function Navbar(props) {

    if (props.location.pathname==="/login") {
        return false;
    }
    return (
       <div>NAVBAR</div>
    );
}
export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

Comment: Yes it worked when I made a seperate NAVBAR component